# Error While Initializing sharepoint tenant site collection names

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Need Help Here is my Code:

```
    public List<string> LoadTenantSiteCollectionNames(Action<string> status)
    {

        try
        {
            this.SPBOXUITenant = new SharePointTenant(this);// Error there
            return this.SPBOXUITenant.StrSiteCollections;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It is giving below error,

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be the different version 15V and 16V because of new update so please follow this step:

1. Check that the both Core as your own project have loaded the 16V assemblies
2. Ensure to set the "Copy local" to true for all SharePoint components assemblies.
3. Rebuild it and make sure the Sharepoint Dlls are included next to your application file.